# How large sample $m$ is enough

Tags: st.statistics, machine-learning, learning-theory

I have a $D$ probability distribution over $X =R^d$, i have two samples $s_1$ and $s_2$ from $D$, each having size $m_1$, $m_2$, a unit ball centered at origin $B(0)$, defined by $B(0)=\{x \in R^2: \|x\|_2 \leqslant 1\}$, How large is enough for $m$ to be, so that we can make sure that with probability at least $\epsilon$ we have $m \leqslant \delta$? any hints?

Comment: Welcome to MO. In order to get better responses it would help to add some context: where did you encounter the problem, what have you tried already yourself, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://bit.ly/2FIHnQa). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: The `bit.ly` link in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374008/how-large-sample-m-is-enough#comment948786_374008) above points to [Creative Commons — Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International — CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). Just posting this in case the URL shortener ends up breaking in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\bar\overline$We have $(n_1-n_2)m=S_m:=Z_1+\cdots+Z_m$, where $Z_i:=X_i-Y_i$, and $X_1,\dots,X_m,Y_1,\dots,Y_m$ are iid Bernoulli random variables (r.v.'s) with parameter $p:=D(B(0))$ -- the probability for a sample item from distribution $D$ to be in $B(0)$. So, the $Z_i$'s are iid r.v.'s with $EZ_i=0$ and $Var\,Z_i=2pq$, where $q:=1-p$. So, by the central limit theorem,
$$\de=P(|n_1-n_2|>\ep)=P(|S_m|>\ep m)\approx2\bar\Phi\Big(\frac{\ep m}{\sqrt{2pqm}}\Big)=2\bar\Phi\Big(\ep\sqrt{\frac m{2pq}}\Big),$$
where $\bar\Phi:=1-\Phi$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

Solving this for $m$, we get
$$m\approx\frac{2pq}{\ep^2}\,\bar\Phi^{-1}(\de/2)^2.$$

**Details in response to OP's comments:**

1. We deal with $Z_i:=X_i-Y_i$ because, as stated above, $(n_1-n_2)m=Z_1+\cdots+Z_m$.
2. $Var\,Z_i=Var\,X_i+Var(-Y_i)=Var\,X_i+(-1)^2Var\,Y_i=Var\,X_i+Var\,Y_i=pq+pq=2pq$.
3. $$\de\approx2\bar\Phi\Big(\ep\sqrt{\frac m{2pq}}\Big) \iff \bar\Phi\Big(\ep\sqrt{\frac m{2pq}}\Big)\approx\de/2 \iff 
   \ep\sqrt{\frac m{2pq}}\approx\bar\Phi^{-1}(\de/2)\iff
   m\approx\frac{2pq}{\ep^2}\,\bar\Phi^{-1}(\de/2)^2.$$

Comment: If you read the answer carefully you see that there is only one place where the ball itself (or its center) is used and that is in the definition of $p$. The number $p$ is the probability of any single point drawn from distribution $D$ to land in this ball. For balls at different location you might get a different actual value of $p$, but if you still call this the abstract letter $p$ (and write $q = 1 - p$) all of the answer stays the same.

Comment: @RhastaShaman : I have added the details you requested.

Comment: @RhastaShaman please note that Iosif and I are not the same person; do the edits Iosif made to the original answer answer your questions?

Comment: @RhastaShaman : I am sorry to have to say this, but even my previous detalization would not be needed even for a beginning researcher with a sufficient promise.This is not to offend, but rather to help you: if you continue having such difficulties with this answer (even with the secondary school algebra), perhaps you should consider another occupation, for your own good.